# Can function declaration and function expression be used interchangeably?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, functional-programming

I'm learning about functions in Javascript but getting confused about the use of function declaration and function expression.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
function callFunction(fn) {
  fn();
}

// function expression
var sayHello1 = function() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}

// function declaration
function sayHello2() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}

callFunction(sayHello1); // Hello World!
callFunction(sayHello2); // Hello World!
```

We can easily see that when passing `sayHello1` (function expression) and `sayHello2` (function declaration) into `callFunction(fn)`, both generate the same output `Hello World!`.

Is there any real case that I **must** use only function declaration/ function expression or I can use them **interchangeably** all the time?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

They both have their use-cases. Function declarations are *[hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)* to the top of your script and can be called before they're definition appears while function expressions can only be called after the declaration.

```
sayHello1(); // Won't work since variable expression is created after call
sayHello2(); // Will work since function declarations are hoisted

var sayHello1 = function() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}

function sayHello2() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

A named function expression can be useful for recursive calls:

```
var sayHello1 = function sayHelloFunc() {
  if (/* something */) {
    sayHelloFunc()
  }
}
```